# How to manage networking and storage in HashiCorp nomad environment?

Tags: docker, networking, storage, nomad

I'm curious how to manage networking and storage for containers (persistent data) managed by `nomad` and running on Docker hosts if one does not want to run k8s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad storage it seems `nomad` has started to use CSI (Container Storage Interface) plugins, see https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/csi_plugin

Ad network, there's support for CNI (Container Network Interface), see https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/job-specification/network#network-examples